# Grub Power Down If Idle

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, power-management

So, I have reign over 200 PCs at my work place, which are all dual boot Win 7 and Ubuntu. We want to encourage usage of both OSes, so there is no timeout to the GRUB screen. GRUB will remain on screen until an OS is picked and it will function as normal. The consequence of this however, is that the machines regularly get left on for a very long time.

Is there a way to run a script within GRUB itself, to shutdown the machine if it's been idle for X minutes? This would have huge power saving for us.

For reference, the machines are running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, GRUB version "1.99-21ubuntu3.10". I wasn't sure whether this belonged in SuperUser or here, but because it's GRUB focused I popped it here. Feel free to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easier if you add a custom option to the grub menu. File `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Add following entries:

```
menuentry 'System shutdown' {
    halt        
}
```

Now set a time-out of X minutes and make this new option default and the machine shuts itself down after X minutes idle time and then run `update-grub`.

Comment: I assume only possible with grub2(?)

Comment: A very elegant solution and it worked like a charm. Edited `/etc/default/grub` to change default entry and timeout seconds, then ran `update-grub`. Thanks!